# In excel, how to do a vlookup where the table array has only part of the lookup value

Tags: excel, vlookup

If these are my lookup values:

```
Red donkey
Blue donkey
Green sheep
Red sheep
```

And these are values from the first column in my table array:

```
donkey
sheep
```

How can I make my vlookup see that donkey or sheep is in my lookup value? My best attempt so far:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$E,K2)),vlookup(K2,Sheet2!$E$1:$F$5,2,FALSE),0)
```

Comment: Why not just set the vlookup to approximate match? =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K2,$E$1:$F$5,2,TRUE),"")

Comment: I've never had success with approximate matches. I always get some inaccurate results, and I did in this instance as well.

Comment: Not an answer so not providing it as such but perhaps this link may be of use: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Comment: I have the fuzzy lookup add-in. While it can be useful, the project I'm working on could one day be audited by the IRS, so I'd like it to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear from some frantic googling that there is an elegant built in solution for matching against a range (1:1 cell checks are easy enough).

I've written a basic function that you can adjust if required:

```
Public Function FuzzyMatch(ValueToFind As String, rng As Range)
Dim var As Variant
For Each var In rng
    If InStr(1, StrConv(var.Value, vbUpperCase), StrConv(ValueToFind, vbUpperCase)) > 0 Then
        FuzzyMatch = var.Address
        Exit Function
    End If
Next var
FuzzyMatch = "Not Found"
End Function
```

Usage in this case would be:

```
=FuzzyMatch(K2,Sheet2!$E$1:$F$5)
```

It currently returns the cell address (to be used with indirect for example), but you could change the following line:

```
FuzzyMatch = var.Address
```

to var.value, var.row, var.column, etc.

Comment: I'm getting an error stating "Ambiguous Name: FuzzyMatch". When I start to type in the function, I see the auto-fill populate as "FuzzyMatch", so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: No such error on my end, check you don't have any other subs, functions, or modules called "FuzzyMatch"